# Delphi 2007 - Compile errors on updating Indy from 10.5.1.1 to 10.6.2.0

Tags: delphi, delphi-2007, indy10

I recently updated the stock Indy that installs with Delphi 2007 (I think it is 10.5.1.1) with 10.6.2.0, which I downloaded from GitHub.

I'm now getting a compile error:

```
EAttachmentFileNotFound.IfFalse (FileExists (parActualAttachmentFileID), 'File ' + parActualAttachmentFileID + ' not found.') ;    
Error: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'IfFalse'
```

The fragment is from my own code but I'm pretty sure that bit came from something I found probably on S/Overflow.

I received a couple of other errors also:

```
SMTPClient.AuthType           := atDefault ;    
Error: E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'atDefault'
```

and

```
SMTPClient.OnWork             := EmailThread.EmailOnWork ;
Error: E2010 Incompatible types: 'Int64' and 'Integer'
```

but the first is a member that was renamed, and the second a data type that was changed.  While these were a simple enough workaround, I'm left wondering

- whether there was ever a "breaking changes" document generated.
- maybe I accidentally somehow got the wrong source set.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`EAttachmentFileNotFound` is not a standard Indy exception, so it must be coming from your own code, or another 3rd party library.

Delphi 2007 was released almost 16 years ago.  A lot has changed in Indy during that time. In fact, I think the changes you mention were actually made prior to, or maybe around, the release of Delphi 2007 (as they already existed in Indy's code in early 2008).

For instance:

- in `EIdException`, the `If(True|False)` methods were removed (I don't know when exactly that change happened).  In which case, you will have to use your own `if` and `raise` expressions now, eg:

  ```pascal
  if not FileExists(parActualAttachmentFileID) then
    raise EAttachmentFileNotFound.Create('File ' + parActualAttachmentFileID + ' not found.');
  ```
- in `TIdComponent`, the `AWorkCount/Max` parameters of the `OnWork...` events were changed from `Integer` to `Int64` in 2006 (see [OnWork Events changed to 64 bit](https://www.indyproject.org/2006/05/25/onwork-events-changed-to-64-bit/) on [Indy's blog](https://www.indyproject.org/blog/)).
- in `TIdSMTP`, the `atDefault` value was renamed to `satDefault` (again, I don't know exactly when this change was made).

So, you need to update your code accordingly.

> I'm left wondering whether there was ever a "breaking changes" document generated.

No such document was ever created, no.  However, changes that affect user code are typically announced on [Indy's blog](https://www.indyproject.org/blog/), under the [Changelog](https://www.indyproject.org/category/changelog/) category.

Comment: Thanks Remy.  It all makes sense now.